# CLR Integration issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I am trying to follow a simple example of CLR integration in Sql Server 2008 with C# following:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2008/87743/

But when I try to deploy the project it throws an error:

> Beginning deployment of assembly SimpleCLRIntegrationNew.dll to
>   server xxxxxxxxx\SQLExpress : TableName C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamData\Microsoft.Data.Schema.SqlClr.targets(96,5):
>   error : Could not connect to server xxxxxxxxxx\SQLExpress BlogData :
>   Login failed for user 'sa'.

However connection is correct and working

Comment: This must be some strange new meaning of "working" that I was not previously aware of... ;-) If the computer says the login has failed then I'd trut that that is what has happened. though I suppose it could possibly be broad enough to cover permissions problems... I assume the sa account has all the permissions it could possibly want?

Comment: By working I mean connection is verified and credentials are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the technical background here, but I noticed the following problem:

When in VisualStudio, check the Project Properties, and under the Database Tab you have the Connection string.

It looks something like this:

```
Data Source=[ServerName];Initial Catalog=[DBName];Integrated Security=True
```

I unfortunately didn't copy the connection string from before - but instead of `Integrated Security=True` it had something with `...User...`. I think I had UserID=sa specified, but don't remember exactly, and I don't know why the connection string was set that way.

I clicked the Browse-button and refreshed the connection (chose my DB and clicked 'OK'). The connection string for the project was reset with the `Integrated Security=True option`set.

I don't know if it matters, but in my CLR I'm connecting to the db using `"context connection=true"`